# Crear funcion de consulta de existencia de dato de forma generica

Tags: mvc, cakephp

```
public function consultar_existencia($campo) {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->layout = false;
            $this->loadModel('Client');
            $existe = $this->Client->find('count', array(
                'conditions' => array($campo => $this->request->data('Field')['Data'])));
        }
        echo json_encode($existe);
    }
```

Hola, tengo esa función en el controlador, la voy a usar para validar si un dato ya existe en la BD, la idea es hacerle unos cambios, pero ps he tenido algunos inconvenientes les voy a mostrar :

`public function consultar_existencia($campo)` //campo es por el campo que se va a comparar en la BD, y la idea tambien seria enviarle el modelo al que va a consultar agregando algo como `$model` en los parametros, y en esta linea se cargaría así:  `$this->loadModel($model);`, y por ahi creo que iriamos bn, el problema llega en esta linea :

```
$existe = $this->Client->find('count', array(
                    'conditions' => array($campo => $this->request->data('Field')['Data'])));
```

ya que en esa linea se hace un llamado a un modelo en especifico, y mi pregunta es, hay alguna forma de decirle que consulte el modelo cargado actualmente? algo como

```
$this->getLoadModel()->find('count',  array(
                    'conditions' => array($campo => $this->request->data('Field')['Data'])));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar las famosas [Variables variables](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php) de PHP, en la documentación encontramos que existen las propiedades variables y se pueden utilizar de esta forma:

```
$a = 'propiedad';
$this->{$a};
```

Lo que equivaldría a hacer esto:

```
$this->propiedad;
```

Como dijiste que ya tienes la variable `$model`, puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
$this->{$model}->find('count',  array(
                'conditions' => array($model . '.' . $campo => $this->request->data('Field')['Data'])));
```